# Evaluate the integral: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (x) dx}{x^2+2x+4}$ using Feynmann integration (differentiation under integral)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

$$I(x) =  \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (x) dx}{x^2+2x+4}$$

$$I( \alpha) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (\alpha x) dx}{x^2+2x+4}$$

$$I'( \alpha) = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(\alpha) (x^2+2x+4)}$$

$$I'( \alpha) =  \frac{1}{(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2 + (\sqrt{3})^2}$$

$$ x+1=t$$

$$I'( \alpha) =  \frac{1}{(\alpha)} \int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2 + (\sqrt{3})^2}   $$

$$I'( \alpha) =  \frac{1}{(\alpha)(\sqrt{3})}  \arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{3}} \Big|_1^\infty  $$

$$I'( \alpha) = \frac{\pi}{3\times \sqrt{3}\times\alpha}$$

I am unsure what to do next as if I integrate wrt. alpha I get my limits from 1 to infinity and I am getting infinity as the resultant. The answer given is $\frac{\pi\ln2}{3\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Please check if I edited is correctly.

Comment: yes thank you, the formatting went awry after posting

Comment: Looks good, you just need to put alpha equal to 1. Also you have a missing factor of 1/2 in arctan infinity which is pi/2

Comment: Keep in mind anything that is like $\log(ax)$ is generally useless for Feynman trick because it simplifies to $\log a + \log x$. Not only did the $\log x$ not matter because you're essentially adding an unrelated constant to the entire integral rather than just the log term, you can't plug in $0$ or $\infty$ because they explode (and justifiably so). You're left with needing to know the value of $I(1)$ in order to compute the value of $I(1)$ every time.

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks for the answer

Comment: @SineoftheTime I'm not aware of that, could you link to some resource for it?

Comment: @jfx it's usually called Feynman trick, not Feynman integration. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under $x\to 2x$, one has
$$I =  \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (x) dx}{x^2+2x+4} =\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (2x)dx}{x^2+x+1}=\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln 2dx}{x^2+x+1}+ \frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (x) dx}{x^2+x+1}.$$
The second integral is zero under $x\to1/x$. It is easy to get the first integral. I omit the details.